# Contradiction in the negative definiteness of Killing form

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the lie algebra of a compact lie group, so that the Killing form $(,)$ is negative definite.  Let the root space decomposition $\mathfrak g =\mathfrak h \oplus \oplus_{\alpha \neq 0} \mathfrak g_\alpha$ be given.

If $e \in \mathfrak{g_\alpha}$ for $\alpha \neq 0$, then $\alpha(h)(e,e)=([h,e],e)=([e,h],e)=-\alpha(h)(e,e)$ and $(e,e)=0$.  This contradicts the form being negative definite.

Where is this contradiction coming from?

Comment: In general invariance of the inner product gets you that $([x,y],z)=([z,x],y)$.  To be sure we have the signs correct we can check in the case of $sl_n$: $([x,y],z)=tr((xy-yx)z)=tr(xyz)-tr(yxz)=tr(zxy)-tr(xzy)=tr([z,x]y)=([z,x],y)$

Now let $x=h$, $y=e$ and $z=e$.

Comment: (the above comment was a response to another comment, since deleted, asking for clarification on the step $([h,e],e)=([e,h],e)$)

Comment: You just showed elegantly that a real Lie algebra with negative definite Killing form does not contain any root space $\mathfrak g_\alpha$., i.e. there is no such decomposition as in your first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

One does not have a root space decomposition when $\mathfrak g$ is the lie algebra of a compact lie group.  This is because any complex lie group is necessarily not compact.

Comment: The last statement is not true, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_Lie_group). There are compact complex Lie groups.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I forgot about tori.  But other than these and discrete groups I think I am right.